# Building a mySQL database to model a graph

Tags: mysql, sql, database, graph, directed-graph

So I'm trying to build a database using mySQL to represent a generic directed graph. This means I need to use directed arcs going from one node to the other and represent it in SQL. Graphs in SQL aren't too difficult but I'm not exactly sure how to model directions.

Any ideas on how to model this kind of database?

Comment: Hi. This is too broad, but is nevertheless a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use a primary key of `sourceNode`, `destinationNode`. If you do this, all of the arcs are inherently directed.